# Display comment count of referencing nodes

Tags: views, users

I have two content types, **Forum** and **Discussion** (urelated to the core forum module). The content type **Discussion** has a node reference to the **Forum** it belongs named field_forum.
I would like to create a views list which show nodes of **Forum** with no. of comments of nodes **Discussion** referencing to it.

Apparently, not a problem:

Just create a view of **Forum** with a reference "Entity Reference: Referencing entity" (A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via field_forum) and then add a "Content: Comment count" field using this reference, set aggregation to on and set aggregation type for this field as sum.

However, my problem is that, even if I DO NOT check the option "Require this relationship" when I create the relationship, still adding comment count field make forums without any discussion to be excluded from the view, while I want all forum to be there, with or without discussions.

If I remove the "Comment count" field, all forums are visible. Strange enough, using the same techniques for counting the discussions works without problems.

This MAY be related to [#1349080](https://www.drupal.org/node/1349080) but unfortunately it works with or without the patch in #231 (that solves similar problems in other contests).

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the following workaround (patched #231 of [#1349080](https://www.drupal.org/node/1349080) required):
add a second level relation discussion->comments and then use the aggregation with count distinct operator over the id field of the comments.